# How to Pass class name Dynamically to List at Run Time C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I need to pass the class name as Dynamically to List in Function but I am getting the error as below..

```
 public void  updateList <T>( T clazz, string classData)
 {                      

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_response) == false)
     {
         List<clazz> list_of_measurements_Original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<clazz>>(json_response);
     } // Getting error for ClassType in List
 }
```

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'clazz' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a number of classes and I want to update dynamically by the same Generic function by passing the Class name or by enum.
I have also used the Dynamic Keyword as a function parameter but no result. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

'clazz' is a parameter while the compiler searches for a type. You don't need to pass the type as a parameter, this is what the generics are for. Try this:

```
    public void  updateList <T>(string classData)
    {

         List<T> objlist = new List<T>(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
List<clazz> objlist = new List<clazz>();
```

To

```
List<T> objlist = new List<T>();
```

Here `T` is a type parameter which is a placeholder for a specific type. The compiler changes the `T` to whatever type you pass. You can't pass a variable (clazz) as a type argument of a generic class.

Comment: Even though this is leading to the right answer, try avoiding change from/to answers.  Try explain why they need to change.

Comment: @Johan Thanks for the tip